# Covariance of Brownian-motion-like processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk, markov-process

We know that $\operatorname{Cov}(B_s,B_t)=\min(s,t)$ if $B_t$ is Brownian motion.

What is $\operatorname{Cov}(B_{f(s)},B_{f(t)})$ for some injective $f$?

How can I write $B_{f(t)}$ in an Ito process form $dX=\mu(X,t)dt+\sigma(X,t)dB_t$, or Ito integral?

Comment: cov $ = f(s) \wedge f(t)$, if possible want $\int \sqrt{f(s)^{\prime}} dB_s$

Comment: sounds correct, can you please emphasize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ and $s,t \in [0,\infty)$. Then

$$\DeclareMathOperator{cov}{cov} \cov(B_{f(s)},B_{f(t)}) = \min \{f(s),f(t)\}$$

since $\cov(B_u,B_v)=\min\{u,v\}$ holds for all $u,v \in [0,\infty)$, so in particular for $u:=f(s)$, $v:=f(t)$.

Concerning your second question:

> Theorem: Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a continuous local martingale, $X_0=0$. Then
>   there exists a Brownian motion $(W_t)_t$ (with respect to a filtration
>   $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \geq 0}$) such that $X_t = W_{[X]_t}$ where $[X]$
>   denotes the compensator of $X$.

(You can find some more information [here](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/), it's theorem 1.)

In this case: If there exists a function $g$ such that $f(t)=\int_0^t g(s)^2 \, ds$,  then we can define

$$X_t := \int_0^t g(s) \, dB_s$$

which gives $[X]_t = \int_0^t g(s)^2 \, ds=f(t)$. By applying the theorem we obtain that there exists a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ such that $$X_t = \int_0^t g(s)^2 \, dB_s = W_{[X]_t} = W_{f(t)}$$

This works in particular if $f$ is differentiable and $f(0)=0$, put $g(s) := \sqrt{f'(s)}$. Of course that's not what you were looking for since you wanted to find a representation as an Itô process for a given Brownian motion.

The problem is the following: You could define (as above)

$$X_t := \int_0^t g(s) \, dB_s$$

where $g(s) := \sqrt{f'(s)}$, $f(0)=0$. Then $X_t$ is a centered Gaussian random variable with variance $f(t)$ and $X_t-X_s$ has variance $f(t)-f(s)$ which means that $X_t$ has the same distribution as the time-changed Brownian motion $B_{f(t)}$. But they are not necessarily the same processes! If you choose for example $f(t):=2t$ you obtain

$$X_t = \int_0^t \sqrt{2} \, dB_s = \sqrt{2} B_t$$

and this is clearly not the same process as $B_{f(t)} = B_{2t}$. On the other hand we know that $W_t := \sqrt{2} \cdot B_{\frac{t}{2}}$ is a Brownian motion and obviously $$X_t = \sqrt{2} \cdot B_{t} = \sqrt{2} \cdot B_{\frac{2t}{2}} = W_{2t} = W_{f(t)}$$

---

Remark:

1. Let $X_t := \int_0^t f_s \, dB_s$ where $f: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds\right)<\infty$. Then $(X_t)_t$ is a martingale and the compensator is given by $$[X]_t = \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds$$ If $f$ is deterministic, i.e. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we know therefore that $(X_t)$ has a deterministic compensator.
2. Let's consider the process $(t,\omega) \mapsto B(f(t),\omega)$ where $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is a deterministic injective function such that $f(0)=0$. In this case $f$ determines how fast you run through the trajectories $(t,\omega) \mapsto B(t,\omega)$. For example $f(t):=2t$ means that you run through the trajectories twice as fast.

Comment: thanks!! wonderful answer! can you please give example for $f(x)=x^2$ so i'll understand more?

Comment: I also dont understand how you took the compensator. if it's only to vanish the mean, why do you define $X$ with $g$ rather than $g^2$?

Comment: Well, $f(x) = x^2$ is not that easy... you obtain $X_t = \int_0^t \sqrt{2s} \, dB_s$ and it's much more difficult to see how you can write this as $W_{t^2}$ for some Brownian motion $W$. Concerning the compensator: For $Y_t := \int_0^t h_s \, dB_s$ one can show that the compensator is given by $[Y]_t = \int_0^t h_s^2 \, ds$. The idea to define $X$ with $g$ is that this implies that $X_t$ has the same distribution as $B_{f(t)}$.

Comment: ok. let me ask you another question. let $f(x)$ run over all functions possible. so what are all possible $B_{f(t)}$? is this the set of all centered Ito processes?

Comment: For a fixed brownian motion $B$: No. If you consider the process $(t,\omega) \mapsto B(f(t),\omega)$ (for some deterministic function $f$), you modify the "speed" of your brownian motion. For example $f(t) := 2t$ means that you run through the trajectories twice as fast.

Comment: But if you have some Itô process $X_t = \int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$ we know (from the theorem above) that there exists a Brownian motion $(W_t)_t$ such that $W_{g(t)} = X_t$ where $g(t) := [X]_t$ is the compensator of $X$. (And as the example above shows, we cannot expect $W_t = B_t$.)

Comment: so one may say that this spans all processes of the form of one Ito integral, while as known from wiener chaos decomposition, all possible Ito processes are sums of iterated Ito integrals. what about second order iterated integral? will it be $min(min(...))$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide an answer to this question... probably it would be a good idea to start a new question for this one, if you are interested in further details.

Comment: many thanks for your great help!